# How to display video in gallery view like image?

Tags: android, gallery

I have created a gallery view and I want to display video (like any video link) and I have worked like this

http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.com/2009/09/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html

but its display nothing. I spend whole day but no result. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are trying to display number of video files in gallery ?

Comment: @YugandharBabu yes I want to display no of files in gallery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have got my answer.

I need to create each video thumbnails and display them into gallery like this

```
Bitmap bm = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path1.getPath()+"/"+filenames1[position], MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

and then each video show in the gallery like image.

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite I get what you need, but if you just want to open a single view in a activity maybe a good way to go is using the `ACTION_VIEW` intent - the native way to do it.

```
public void startVideo(String videoAddress){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(videoAddress), "video/3gpp"); // The Mime type can actually be determined from the file
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

However this intent will prompt your users to choose a player for the video. In most of my cases I found using the [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) tag more useful - just display the video full screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

If you want to be able to browse between many videos you can implement loading of the new video using gesture detectors:

```
GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector() {

    @Override
    public void swipeRight() {
        if (currentArticle > 0) {
            currentArticle--;
            loadPage();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeLeft() {
        if (currentArticle == articleList.size()) {
            return;
        } else {
            currentArticle++;
            loadPage();
        }
    }

});

View.OnTouchListener gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
};
```

Hopefully some of my suggestions will prove useful to you!

Comment: Thanks but not useful to me. I am asking for number of videos in gallery

Comment: Isn't the last bit serving your needs? If I get you correctly you need to display a single video at a time? Afterwords you can swipe left-right using the gesture detector...

Answer (score 0):

For play video directly from GridView you have to pass video url in following function

public void playVideo(String url){

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + url), "video/*");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```